# Why wont the json_encoded data show

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I have add chartJS and that works just fine, the problem i have when im trying to add my json_encoded php array in to the data field in chartJS. The problem i have is that the chart wont add my data in to the bars. See the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm7wz.png)

This is how my json_encoded array looks like when im using print_r to output the data

```
[{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"5"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"5"},{"todoCoin":"9"},{"todoCoin":"10"},{"todoCoin":"11"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"8"},{"todoCoin":"10"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"8"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"}]
```

If i remove the json_encode my array looks like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 1 ) [5] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 6 ) [6] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 5 ) [7] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 3 ) [8] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 1 ) [9] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 2 ) [10] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 4 ) [11] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 4 ) [12] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 5 ) [13] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 9 ) [14] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 10 ) [15] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 11 ) [16] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 6 ) [17] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 4 ) [18] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 3 ) [19] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 2 ) [20] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 6 ) [21] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 8 ) [22] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 10 ) [23] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 2 ) [24] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 4 ) [25] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 3 ) [26] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 8 ) [27] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 1 ) [28] => Array ( [todoCoin] => 1 ) ) 1
```

Here is the only html i have

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

and then the javascript

```
<script>
    var myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    // Global Options
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontsize = 18;
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#777";
    var test = 80;
    var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, doughnut, radar, polarArea
        data: {
            labels:['Färdiga todo', 'Tid nedlagt', 'Användare'],
            datasets: [{
                label:'Todo Score', 
                data:[
                    <?php echo json_encode($data);?>,
                    <?php echo json_encode($data);?>,
                    <?php echo json_encode($data);?>
                ], 
                backgroundColor:[
                    'rgba(128,128,0)',
                    'rgba(255,0,0)',
                    'rgba(0,0,255)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#777',
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Överblick på din todoScore',
                fontSize: 25,

            },
            legend:{
                position: "right"
            }
        }   
    });
</script>
```

An example snippet wihtout the php

```js
var myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

// Global Options
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontsize = 18;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#777";
var test = 80;
var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
  type: 'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data: {
    labels: ['Färdiga todo', 'Tid nedlagt', 'Användare'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Todo Score',
      data: [
      [{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"5"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"5"},{"todoCoin":"9"},{"todoCoin":"10"},{"todoCoin":"11"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"8"},{"todoCoin":"10"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"8"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"}],
      [{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"5"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"5"},{"todoCoin":"9"},{"todoCoin":"10"},{"todoCoin":"11"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"8"},{"todoCoin":"10"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"8"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"}],
      [{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"5"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"5"},{"todoCoin":"9"},{"todoCoin":"10"},{"todoCoin":"11"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"6"},{"todoCoin":"8"},{"todoCoin":"10"},{"todoCoin":"2"},{"todoCoin":"4"},{"todoCoin":"3"},{"todoCoin":"8"},{"todoCoin":"1"},{"todoCoin":"1"}]
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(128,128,0)',
        'rgba(255,0,0)',
        'rgba(0,0,255)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#777',
      hoverBorderWidth: 3,
      hoverBorderColor: '#000'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Överblick på din todoScore',
      fontSize: 25,

    },
    legend: {
      position: "right"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on what you've posted I've added a snippet to your question (removes the php and just has the arrays as they would be). If this is wrong, you can click the edit and roll it back to the original :)

Comment: `data` should be an array of numbers. With `json_encode()` you get a json object. Also `"todoCoin":"1"` `"1"` is a string and not a number. Your data should be like `[1,4,5,....,6]` [Chartsjs documentation on data](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#data-structure)

Comment: Well i tried to parse it to a int,  like this  $data[] = (int)$row; But it still does not work...

Comment: `json_encode()` will not work for you, you need to loop through the array and echo the values seperated with commas or you can try `echo implode(", ", $data);`

Comment: if i try to  foreach ($data as $test) {
        echo $test, "\n";
    } I get Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/todo/chartTodo.php on line 19

Comment: try `echo implode(", ", $data);`

Comment: I have it still tells me Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/todo/chartTodo.php on line 18

Comment: is line 18 where you put that? You just need to replace `<?php echo json_encode($data);?>` with `<?php echo implode(", ", $data);?>` in your original code

Comment: I added a snippet on  how my array  looks like now, do you mean i need to remove the json_encode everywhere and only add <?php echo implode(", ", $data);?> in the chart.js?

Answer (score 0):

To output data from your json array, you should use `json_decode`. Assuming `$data` is what you declared your json array with:

```
<?php 
  $decoded_data = json_decode($data);
  foreach ($decoded_data->{'todoCoin'} as $todoCoin) {
    echo $todoCoin;
  }
?>
```

Try that in your `data:[]`

**edit**

I see where I misread that it is a multidimensional array you encoded. This is also why you are seeing array to string conversion error when trying to use `echo`- you have multiple arrays in an array itself. Try this in your `data:[]` property:

```
<?php 
  $decoded = json_decode($data); // decode your json 2d array
  $decoded_array = array(); // create new 1D array
  # break down the first array
  foreach ($decoded as $todoCoins) {
    # break down the second array
    foreach ($todoCoins as $todoCoin) {
      # append each value, ignoring the 'todoCoin' key, to the new 1d array
      array_push($decoded_array, $todoCoin);
    }
  }
  echo implode(", ", $decoded_array); // outputs 1,1,1,1,1,6,5,3,1, etc...
?>
```

Comment: When adding the foreach to the data:[] it only breaks all the code :P

Comment: Please try the updated answer where I posted my **edit** and let me know how it goes. I'm assuming you only wanted to keep your values.